# android zoom in / out not working in custom camera appa

Tags: android, camera, zooming, customization

I have this function to add zoom control to my camera app. This function is called from 
surfaceChanged()

But on many of the devices pressing + / - for zoom out / in shows no effect. These devices support Zoom . Also the code is working on sony xperia , so the code must be correct.

Please help me to fix it. Is there anything more i need to do .

```
public void setZoomControl(Camera.Parameters params) {
    ZoomControls zoomControls = (ZoomControls) findViewById(R.id.CAMERA_ZOOM_CONTROLS);

    if (params.isZoomSupported()) {
        maxZoomLevel = params.getMaxZoom();
        Log.i("max ZOOM ", "is " + maxZoomLevel);
        ;

        zoomControls.setIsZoomInEnabled(true);
        zoomControls.setIsZoomOutEnabled(true);

        zoomControls.setOnZoomInClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (currentZoomLevel < maxZoomLevel) {
                    currentZoomLevel++;
                    camera.startSmoothZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                }
            }
        });

        zoomControls.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (currentZoomLevel > 0) {
                    currentZoomLevel--;
                    camera.startSmoothZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                }
            }
        });
    } else
        zoomControls.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: According to documentation you should check against ``params.isSmoothZoomSupported()`` to see whether ``Camera.startSmoothZoom(..)`` is available.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue . Smoothzoom was not supported. So instead of startSmoothZoom() , we have to call setZoom() and then camera.setparams. Please add your comment as answer, then i can accept it. Thank you

Comment: Harism plzz provide d full if it is working for customise camera.

Comment: preetha plzz provide d full if it is working for customise camera.

Comment: @preetha hi i also want to add zooming functionality in my app, created Custom Camera, but i have some small issues, will you help me?

Comment: @preetha.. even I was also facing the same issue ... instead of SmoothZoom only Zoom was supported.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem.

Don't used startSmoothZoom() method

```
Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
params.setZoom(zoom_value);
camera.setParameters(params);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482825/android-custom-camera-zoom-not-working/42473465#42473465 check this